# Why would you want to include/require multiple times?

Tags: php, include, require

`require` and `include` have the variations `require_once` and `include_once`. They prevent the script from loading a file multiple times.

I think I can safely assume, because the functions exist, that there would be cases where you would need the `require`/`include` function instead of the `require_once`/`include_once` one. But I cannot imagine a case like that. What would that be?

Comment: I use `require` [in a templating engine](https://github.com/halfer/TemplateSystem/blob/master/ControllerBase.php#L52) to include an HTML fragment as many times as required. As it happens, my last bug on that repo was my incorrectly using `require_once`, thus fragments that were used more than once were ignored!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probably the best example would be when giving output. If, say, you had a snippet of HTML that might appear more than once on various pages, you could put it into a separate file and include it as many times as you wanted.

Moreover, it's often unnecessary to use `require_once` or `include_once`. If the file will only be called once (e.g. in `__autoload`) then the simple functions have less overhead, because PHP doesn't need to keep track of whether the file has been included before.

Comment: So if I understand correctly `require_once` and `include_once` are there for sloppy scripters to clean up their mess?

Comment: @Joren To some extent they belong in a past era of PHP, yes, I'd say so.

Comment: Lovely, a mental -1 for PHP and a +1 for you.

Answer (score 1):

One may want to use require_once instead of require if you want to have a variable or constant defined only once. This is helpful for making reusable classes in a very large code base that manages dependencies rapidly. Lets say I have a file A that needs a file B but I already include file C that included file B. Since file B was already included, the program does not have to evaluate that code again to properly evaluate file A. This is a case where you may want to include the file only once.

It helps with managing your dependencies